# How to change JSP version in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am upgrading my old Java webapp using JSP spec 2.0 to tomcat 7 that uses JSP specs 2.2 and the EL specs have changed much in recent versions of Tomcat 7. I have a lot of JSPs that uses old EL that are not compatible with newer versions of EL in JSP 2.2.

My question (Futile alert!), can I somehow change Tomcat 7 to use JSP 2.0 spec. You'd say why don't I use older Tomcat; I can't because I need to use Servlet 3.0 specs.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. If you somehow did, you wouldn't be able to use Servlet 3.0 because your JSP(s) are compiled into Servlets. Tomcat releases are tied to JSP and Servlet versions.

Per the [Apache Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) documentation,

> Apache Tomcat version 7.0 implements the Servlet 3.0 and JavaServer Pages 2.2 specifications from the Java Community Process, and includes many additional features that make it a useful platform for developing and deploying web applications and web services.

Comment: what needs to be done if one wants to use different version of servlet (other than already present in Tomcat Server)? or it's not possible to use different version of servlet ?

Comment: @rohit you use the version of tomcat that implements the desired version of the servlet spec. You can't pick and choose.

Comment: same is applicable for jersey framework? If jersey with a particular version is already present on Tomcat server then one can't bundle different jersey version in war file & deploy on Tomcat server?